# Need to update state when number of rows is unknown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I doubt this is possible but I'd like to hear your thoughts.

I am getting an array which the number of values are unknown.
And I am using a for loop to spread it in a state:

```
 const { letters,number } = route.params
const [arr,setArr] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
        var eachArr = []
        setArr([])
        for (let i = 1; i < Number(number) + 1; i++) {
            eachArr.push(i)
        }  
        setArr(eachArr)
    }, [])
```

Now I use the state to map through to render accordingly

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
        {
            arr.length > 0 && arr.map(num => (
                <View style={styles.placeContainer} key={num}>
                    <View style={styles.place}>
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold',letterSpacing:1 }}>{num} {letters}</Text>
                        <Feather name="check-circle" size={24} color="grey" />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ marginVertical:10 }}>
                      <Progress color={colors.purple} progress={1} width={null} borderWidth={0} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={{ color:colors.white,fontFamily:'viga' }}> this {letters}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{...styles.button,backgroundColor:colors.lightPurple}}>
                        <Text style={{ color:colors.white,fontFamily:'viga' }}> this {letters}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            ))
        }
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
```

I now have a problem. I have two buttons on each of the mapped element/component as you can see above.
I need to listen for a click on one and deactivate the clicked button and then activate the other button.
The problem is that I do not know how to set/update a state based on the which button is clicked since the number of rows are unknown.

I know I can call a function:

```
const callFunc = (val) -> {
console.log(val)
}
```

And call the function when a respective button is clicked and pass the val or sth. While this solves some part of the issue, how do I then deactivate it and active the new button when I didn't set a state for it

Comment: Your question doesnt make sense to me, how you generate the "number" value in the useEffect? Also notice that calling setState in a loop is an anti pattern, for large number you will get multi renders that will simulate a screen freeze.

Comment: @DennisVash I get the numbers as a route parameter. It's passed from the previous screen. I have updated my code, please have a look